# Test download speed from database using app and maximum download speed

Tags: ios, swift, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 as my image storage platform for my app. However, I am finding that the download speed is quite slow. I am using Alamofire with the link to the image in S3 to download my image. I want to test the following

Download speed from Amazon S3 (If it is too slow I need to consider other service). I want to test it on my phone (Wifi, and Cellular) and also find out the maximum download speed.

My images are approximately 200kb to 400kb each. They are displayed in tableview cells. I am looking for an accurate bench mark to compare with what Amazon would expect me to get. Is there some sort of smart way or framework to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS iOS SDK can be used to facilitate your use of S3.
There is a `downloadToURL` method that will help download files.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferUtility.m#L358

You can experiment with accelerated mode to see if this solves your problem.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferUtility.m#L392